# How to check single array contains same value

Tags: c#

```
string currentUrl = "destination/India/India/mumbai";
string[] array = currentUrl.Split('/');
string countryName = "india";
```

In the above example,In C# how can i check that Country name is repeating in url?

Comment: contains method?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By `Count()`ing the appearence of `countryName`

```
string currentUrl = "destination/India/India/mumbai";
string[] array = currentUrl.Split('/');
string countryName = "india";
bool isRepeating = array.Count(x => countryName.Equals(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Distinct method. Something like

```
string currentUrl = "destination/India/mumbai";
string[] array = currentUrl.Split('/');
string countryName = "india";

if (array.Distinct().Count() != array.Count())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate");
}
```

Or you can try blow code

```
string currentUrl = "destination/india/india/mumbai";
string[] array = currentUrl.Split('/');
string countryName = "india";

bool r = array.Where(x => x.Equals(countryName)).Count()>1;
if(r)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate");
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more about you problem ?

Comment: `"destination/destination/India/mumbai"` will also result duplicate but the country name is not repeating

Comment: You can use this bool r= array.Where(x => x.Equals(countryName)).Count()>1;